# Updating existing variable value inside #ifdef?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am new to C++, and I am trying to update a `BOOL` variable in the following block of code :

```cpp
#define REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR 1 

bool rm_by_succ = 0;

#ifdef REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR
    rm_by_succ = 1;
#endif
```

But my *g++* compiler gives me the following error :

```
‘rm_by_succ’ does not name a type
```

Could someone please explain to me what I did wrong ?

Comment: `rm_by_succ = 1;` Statements outside any function are not legal in C++.

Answer (score 2):

As dxiv says, you can't have code outside a function.  You can, however, do this:

```
#ifdef REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR
    bool rm_by_succ = 1;
#else
    bool rm_by_succ = 0;
#endif
```

Better yet, define these variables as `const` and use `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rm_by_succ` is declared in global scope, then you can't re-assign it right after its declaration.  Such code is not allowed in global scope.  You would have to do the re-assignment inside of a function instead, such as `main()`, eg:

```
#define REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR 1 

bool rm_by_succ = false;

int main() {
    #ifdef REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR
    rm_by_succ = true;
    #endif

    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can write the declaration itself more like this instead:

```
#define REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR 1 

bool rm_by_succ =
    #ifdef REMOVE_REPLACED_BY_SUCESSOR
    true
    #else
    false
    #endif
;
```